# Manually download Maven Dependencies

Tags: maven

I am new to Maven. When I try to run `mvn install` [for Kafka Spout - A Storm spout implementation for Kafka], maven tries to fetch the dependencies [various pom's etc.]. How can I manually download those [If suppose one of the sites like conjars.org/repo cant be accessed using CLI for me even with appropriate proxy enabled]? What I mean is where does maven place them so that the runtime finds it? Is it all in the `.m2/` folder? Bit confused with the process.

The exact error I get:

```
Access denied to: http://conjars.org/repo/com/twitter/kafka_2.9.2/0.7.0/
kafka_2.9.2-0.7.0.pom , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.
```

I am not much interested in as to how to get rid of this error but I want to download the stuff manually. I don't use Eclipse.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should download JAR manually and install it to your local repo using maven `install:install-file`. See this post for details

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/

Answer (score 1):

1. you should install nexus, it can mirror all your repos.
2. You can change the config file /maven/conf/m2.conf